# Can we do quick search on non primary details?

Tags: quicksearch

There is a option called 'Search Primary Details Only' under Administer >> Customize Data and Screens >> Search Preference when set to 'No' it works only when searched using search forms like Advance contact search or Find contact search but the quick search on top left corner doesn't respect this setting. Is it a core bug or intended to search on primary details or never supported?

Comment: There's a recent ticket about this. See https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/1557

Comment: Thanks, created a small extension temporary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There has been [discussion](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/1557) going on to implement this in CiviCRM core code, developed a small [extension](https://github.com/pradpnayak/org.civicrm.nonprimaryquicksearch) to do that for time being until its been implemented in core.